# Why owner of schema cannot change owner of table when the table has a different owner- Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema, privileges, owner

The owner of my schema - **public** is called '***eyal***', and the owner of the tabled inside the schema, called '***postgres***'.

I am trying to change my table owner (when im logged to user: '***eyal***') to user: '***eyal***' but i get the error - **"must be owner of the table"**

How is it possible to be an owner of a schema, but without the ability to change the schema tables owners?

I tryed using the following commands:

```
ALTER TABLE public.table_name OWNER TO "eyal";
```

&

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "public"
TO "eyal";
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is it possible to be an owner of a schema, but without the ability
> to change the schema tables owners?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PRIV

> By default, users cannot access any objects in schemas they do not
> own. To allow that, the owner of the schema must grant the USAGE
> privilege on the schema. By default, everyone has that privilege on
> the schema public. To allow users to make use of the objects in a
> schema, additional privileges might need to be granted, as appropriate
> for the object.
>
> A user can also be allowed to create objects in someone else's schema.
> To allow that, the CREATE privilege on the schema needs to be granted.
> In databases upgraded from PostgreSQL 14 or earlier, everyone has that
> privilege on the schema public

So it's like you as schema owner (eyal) granted create and usage privileges to
another user (postgres) then (postgres) is the table owner.
Also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-priv.html#PRIVILEGE-ABBREVS-TABLE
Schema only have two privileges: USAGE and CREATE. So as a schema owner, you can only apply these two privileges to other roles.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) describes this:

> You must own the table to use `ALTER TABLE`. To change the schema or tablespace of a table, you must also have `CREATE` privilege on the new schema or tablespace. [...] To alter the owner, you must also be a direct or indirect member of the new owning role, and that role must have `CREATE` privilege on the table's schema. (These restrictions enforce that altering the owner doesn't do anything you couldn't do by dropping and recreating the table. However, a superuser can alter ownership of any table anyway.)

The alternative is that you are a superuser, who can do anything.